# How to make scrapy use two queues to manage urls?

Tags: python, redis, scrapy, priority-queue

I want to make a focused distributed crawler by scrapy framework and scrapy-redis lib.
Here I need TWO queues, one is called prior_queue, the other one is urls_queue.Both queues maintain sorted requests based on their score. Crawler always takes the first request from prior_queue, until the prior_queue is empty, then move some requests to prior_queue from urls_queue. All requests that are yielded are pushed into urls_queue.
With such requirement, could anyone give me some solution or idea how to implement it? What modules of scrapy should i modify to fit my requirement?

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy have a single queue. You can read more about the queue ordering [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html?#does-scrapy-crawl-in-breadth-first-or-depth-first-order).
To achieve your goals you still can use a request priority. See the request [definition](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request).

```
priority_request = Request(url="http://www.example.com", priority=100)
yield priority_request
request = Request(url="http://www.example.com")
yield request
```